# How to fix weird "channelMax" error rabbitmq rpc?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I created simple client and server. Client sends rpc requests:

```
RabbitTemplate template.convertSendAndReceive(...) ;
```

Server receive it, and answers back:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "#{queue.getName()}")
public Object handler(@Payload String key)...
```

Then I make client send rpc requests asynchronously, simultaneously(which produces lot of concurrent rpc requests).

And unexpectedly receive an error:

> org.springframework.amqp.AmqpResourceNotAvailableException: The channelMax limit is reached. Try later.
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.createChannel(SimpleConnection.java:59)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1208)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.access$200(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1196)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.doCreateBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:599)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:582)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getCachedChannelProxy(CachingConnectionFactory.java:552)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:534)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.access$1400(CachingConnectionFactory.java:99)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createChannel

Rabbitmq client seems create too many channels. How to fix it?
And why my client create them so many?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Channels are cached so there should only be as many channels as there are actual RPC calls in process.

You may need to increase the channel max setting on the broker.

**EDIT**

If your RPC calls are long-lived, you can reduce the time the channel is used by using the `AsyncRabbitTemplate` with an explicit reply queue, and avoid using the direct reply-to feature.

[See the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#async-template).

**EDIT2**

Here is an example using the `AsyncRabbitTemplate`; it sends 1000 messages on 100 threads (and the consumer has 100 threads).

The total number of channels used was 107 - 100 for the consumers and only 7 were used for sending.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So56126654Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So56126654Application.class, args);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "so56126654", concurrency = "100")
    public String slowService(String in) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5_000L);
        return in.toUpperCase();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncTemplate) {
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
        return args -> {
            System.out.println(asyncTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("foo").get());
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                int n = i;
                exec.execute(() -> {
                    RabbitConverterFuture<Object> future = asyncTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("foo" + n);
                    try {
                        System.out.println(future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (TimeoutException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new AsyncRabbitTemplate(connectionFactory, "", "so56126654", "so56126654-replies");
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("so56126654");
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue reeplyQueue() {
        return new Queue("so56126654-replies");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: During simultaneous requests i observe strange situation: the number of connections rise , but never decrease. When I stop sending requests, the actual number of channels doesn't change. I observe it through spring actuator metrics.

May be I should suppress incoming requests? I don't want to just increase "channel max", because the channel count seems grow continuously(and the "channel max" setting would be hit again later).

Comment: You can call `getCacheProperties()` on the `CachingConnectionFactory` to see the status of the channel cache. See [the reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#runtime-cache-properties). The channels should not "keep increasing". As I said, they are cached for reuse.

Comment: I can see from Management UI that channels got created(and they are active) more and more. Virtually no idle channels. It indicates load is too big

Comment: You can use an async template to shorten the time the channel is in use.

Comment: I tried AsyncRabbitTemplate , still have got too many channels.
So, now Im going to define explicit reply queue. The only one queue for several instances of producers and receivers

Comment: but I still don't understand why explicit reply queue could help?

Comment: Did you use an external listener container with a reply queue (instead of direct reply-to, which requires the channel to be checked out)? If so, something strange is going on; can you share a small project that reproduces the issue? When direct reply-to is used, the channel is reserved until the reply is received. When not, the send is performed and the channel is put back in the cache almost immediately; the reply comes back on the container's channel instead.

Comment: I tested it with direct reply-to. But now Im trying to do without this property

Comment: It's not about running the `RabbitTemplate` asynchronously, it's about using the `AsyncRabbitTemplate` - see the update to my answer. Even though the service takes 5 seconds to reply, only 7 channels were used to send 1000 requests.

Comment: If you are using publisher confirms, the channel will remain "in use" until the confirm is returned; this can cause more channels to be needed at very high volumes. If possible, using `template.invoke()` around multiple sends can alleviate this condition.

Comment: Russel I actually cannot grep the meaning of invoke() command from description. And cannot find any precise description on the internet.
Can you please clarify what this method does ?

Comment: See [Scoped Operations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#scoped-operations) in the reference manual.

Comment: Finally I managed to address channelMax error by restraining publisher threads : execute convertSendAndReceive in ThreadPool with limited pool size(equal to RabbitListener concurrency attribute). 
PS In that particular case , RabbitTemplate make sense in place of AsyncRabbitTemplate

Comment: do you have a sample for this